# Is there a better way for making a list of ancestors in this program?

Tags: prolog

```
same_gender_parent(ID, L) :-
    person(ID, _, _, P, _, _, _),
    member(ID, D),
    family(R1, R2, D),
    write(member(ID,D)),
    lice(R1, _, _, PY, _, _, _),
    (P = PY -> Parent is R1 ; Parent is R2) -> append([Parent], L, L1),
    %week_diff(ID, Parent),
    same_gender_parent(Parent, L1).
same_gender_parent(_, []).
```

In the code above, I have made it so that it takes a person(ID, name, lastname, gender, date, birthplace, livingplace), and checks if person by ID is a member of said family(parent1, parent2, [children]), after which it checks which parent's gender is the same as the child's and puts that parent's ID in the list.

The issue is that it works until a person has no ancestors, after which the member() function returns a fail. When tracing the program, it successfully checks for and puts the ancestors in a list, but again, fails when it tries to do it with a person with no further ancestors.

How can I improve this to prevent this from happening?

Note, week_diff is from a different part which works by itself.

Comment: What question do you want "same_gender_parent" to answer? In order to check the gender of a parent, that data must actually be present.

Comment: As I said, it does its work properly, it returns all the same gendered ancestors of a person, but the issue is when a person at the top has no ancestor, member(ID, D) fails because said person doesn't belong in any list of children, and it returns a fail for the whole function. My question is how can I avoid this failure?

Comment: member/2 is not what's failing. As evidence:
?- member(a, D).
D = [a|$VAR(_)] ;
D = [$VAR(_),a|$VAR(_)] ;
D = [$VAR(_),$VAR(_),a|$VAR(_)]  and so on.